# C++ Why is variable a function and not an object?

Tags: c++, function, object, most-vexing-parse

This title may not be completely accurate--it's based on my best guess on what is happening and I figured it was better than "Can someone explain what is happening with this code?"

Anyway, I have this code:

```
class Class1 { };

class Class2
{
public:
   Class2(Class1 other){}
};

void func(Class2 x){}

int main()
{
   Class2 x(Class1());
   func(x);             //Compile Error

   Class1 y1;
   Class2 y2(y1);
   func(y2);            //Compiles fine
   return 0;
}
```

So when I compile it, the line marked as "Compile Error" provides an error in g++ 4.9:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:10: error: could not convert ‘x’ from ‘Class2 (*)(Class1 (*)())’ to ‘Class2’
    func(x);
          ^
```

clang++ 3.4.1 provides a similar error.

My best guess is that it thinks that "x" is some sort of function that returns a Class2, instead of a Class2 itself, but...why is this happening?  I would think that the call to Class1 returns some anonymous Class1 which is passed into Class2's constructor.

Comment: I reverted your edit. Please don't add the answer to the question. That's what answers are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class2 x(Class1());` is a function declaration due to a **vexing parse** (google skills come in handy here).

Alternative:

```
Class2 x((Class1()));
Class2 x{Class1()};
```

Comment: Awesome!  In 11 minutes when the accept button unlocks, I'll accept this answer.  Thanks for your help!  I hadn't heard of "vexing parse" before, and without that specific term, googling for a solution was a bit difficult :-)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is because this line

```
Class2 x( Class1());
```

declares a function actually and not an object. This is known as *vexing parse*.
To avoid this issue you should write:

```
Class2 x((Class1()));
```

or

```
Class1 y;
Class2 x( y);
```